# IDTSVariable100 in custom class

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm writing a custom class to use in some script components. I need to use the SSIS `IDTSVariable100` variable in a c# class library.
These references don't work:

> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
>
> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

`Dts` is not referenced in `Microsoft.SqlServer`. Can it be referenced? Where are these SSIS variables defined? What is the namespace I need to include?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap`? Are you aware that assembly references and `using` directives are separate things?

Comment: No I did not. Yes I am aware. It also solved my problem so if you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the help page for [`IDTSVariable100`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.idtsvariable100.aspx), and note these lines:

> **Namespace:**  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
>   **Assembly:**  Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap (in Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll)

[`using` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) are for creating aliases or avoiding needing to specify a complete namespace. But if the assembly mentioned isn't referenced by your project, then the type won't be available. You need to add this reference to your project.